# Cannot use XFont using PDFsharp in Azure WebSite

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, pdfsharp

I deploy an application that uses PDFsharp to create a few PDF files on the fly to an azure website.
It is working well in development, but when I move to azure and run the application, when the program tries to create the new XFont object to format the output I receive the error message

Font data could not retrieved

How can I solve this?
  Thanks,
    luca

Answer (score 0):

Give your application more rights (full trust) or use Private Fonts.

http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PrivateFonts-sample.ashx
IIRC with PDFsharp 1.32 private fonts only work with the WPF build of PDFsharp.